# How are zombie processes handled when the parent dies?

Tags: process, zombie-process

Which technique does the Unix system use to remove zombie processes whose parent has terminated?

Comment: This SE is better suited if ask only a single question in a post or restrict yourself to questions concerning the same issue. Second show some research effort rather then just copying your homework assignment. For instance: ow do you know that there are only or at least 3 ways?....

Comment: I am studying actually and these are revision questions, separate ones so I dont think they are related. I can't find the answer anywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a process's parent dies, init (process 1) adopts the process. It will then reap adopted precesses that are or become zombies.

Reaping is normally done by the parent, as the parent needs to know when the child dies. It also has to stop the pid of the child being reused, until the parent knows, so that the parent does not signal the wrong process (signals the correct pid, but the pid now belongs to a new process.). In the reaping process the parent should forget about the child.

Answer (score 0):

If a process terminates,and that process has children in the zombie state,the parents process ID of all the zombie children is set to 1(the init process) which will inherit the children and clean them up(i.e., init will wait for them,which removes the zombie).